# pandas timedelta resample weeks fails

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

## Actual Question

As in this small example shown, I try to weekly resample a pandas dataframe:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{
    'A' : datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.now(),
    'B' : 2
},{
    'A' : datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.now(),
    'B' : 3
}])

df = df.set_index('A')

df.resample('W', how="mean")
```

this throws an `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: 'Week' object has no attribute 'nanos'
```

(Note: If I resample by `"D"` the problem does not occur)

If I instead cast the index to a datetime:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.values)
df.resample('W', how="mean")
```

the resampling works as well.
**Question:** Is there a pandas timedelta type that does not rely on nano seconds?
**Or:** Do you have any more elegant way than exploit `datetime` for `timedelta`?

---

## Full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3266, in resample
    return sampler.resample(self).__finalize__(self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 98, in resample
    rs = self._resample_timestamps(kind='timedelta')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 272, in _resample_timestamps
    self._get_binner_for_resample(kind=kind)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 122, in _get_binner_for_resample
    self.binner, bins, binlabels = self._get_time_delta_bins(ax)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 236, in _get_time_delta_bins
    name=ax.name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tdi.py", line 167, in __new__
    closed=closed)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tdi.py", line 235, in _generate
    index = _generate_regular_range(start, end, periods, offset)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tdi.py", line 895, in _generate_regular_range
    stride = offset.nanos
AttributeError: 'Week' object has no attribute 'nanos'
```

## Versions

```
>>> pd.__version__
'0.16.2'
>>> np.__version__
'1.10.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the difference is that pandas uses numpy's datetime64 while the python datetime class is something different. When you call

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.values)
```

you are casting from the datetime.datetime object which you created to the numpy.datetime64 object that resample takes as an argument.

Comment: sure, but in how does that answer my questions ?

Comment: Well, your question was:

Question: Is there a pandas timedelta type that does not rely on nano seconds?

To which I answered:

Yes, numpy.datetime64

You also asked: 

Or: Do you have any more elegant way than exploit datetime for timedelta?

To which the answer is:

No, becuase there is no equivalent to datetime.datetime.now() in numpy.datetime64. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html